# which rows are duplicates to each other

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I have got a database with a lot of columns. Some of the rows are duplicates (on a certain subset). 
Now I want to find out which row duplicates which row and put them together.
For instance, let's suppose that the data frame is

```
     id       A        B       C
0     0       1        2       0
1     1       2        3       4
2     2       1        4       8
3     3       1        2       3
4     4       2        3       5
5     5       5        6       2
```

and subset is

```
['A','B']
```

I expect something like this:

```
     id       A        B       C
0     0       1        2       0
1     3       1        2       3
2     1       2        3       4
3     4       2        3       5
4     2       1        4       8
5     5       5        6       2
```

Is there any function that can help me do this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for mask with all dupes, then flter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
L = ['A','B']
m = df.duplicated(L, keep=False)

df = pd.concat([df[m].sort_values(L), df[~m]], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   id  A  B  C
0   0  1  2  0
1   3  1  2  3
2   1  2  3  4
3   4  2  3  5
4   2  1  4  8
5   5  5  6  2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! Got it completely :)